# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

Tags: subprocess, micropython

```
import subprocess


def check_output(cmd):
    """ https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen
        Implementation subprocess.check_output() for Python 2.6
     """
    process_list = []
    cmd_list = cmd.strip().split("|")
    for i, sub_cmd in enumerate(cmd_list):
        STDIN = None
        if i > 0:
            STDIN = process_list[i - 1].stdout
        process_list.append(subprocess.check_output(sub_cmd, stdin=STDIN, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True))
    if len(process_list) == 0:
        return ''
    output = process_list[i].communicate()[0]
    return output

print(check_output('ls -la /var | grep log'))
```

I am facing issue of AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output' in Thonny python Every time run my program, I tried call() also but it is showing same error

Comment: I can't repro. Did you name your script `subprocess.py` by any chance? (Still it does have a method named `check_output`, which however is probably also more confusing than useful.)

Comment: Python can natively list files, sort them, and search for substrings; if that subprocess is a genuine example of your use case, the simplest solution by far is to replace those constructs with native Python code.

Comment: Or are you genuinely trying to port this code back to Python 2.6? Then indeed `subprocess` does not have this method. But then the recursive call makes no sense whatsoever; did you mean `Popen`?

Comment: I have also tried using subprocess.Popen() but i am facing same issue, besides does any knows how can i check all the attribute of module

Comment: Simply `dir(module)` at the REPL prompt. Some modules are poorly designed for this use case, but `subprocess` is not one of them.

Comment: You have not responded to my requests for clarification. Is the target really Python 2.6? Did you name your file `subproces.py`?